How to fix the booting issue in Ubuntu on a virtualbox?
While upgrading Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04. I had interrupted the process and now an error is being displayed and it is not booting up
The error displayed is
Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  UUID:  <long-number> does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)_

I can't change the root delay since no boot directory exist in the busybox .

At the grub menu; select an older kernel (from your jammy or 22.04 system) and let it boot up; you should then be able to have the upgrade of pacakges continue.   Your cancelled process mean the noble or 24.04 kernel likley didn't complete install/build, thus the failure to boot & you're left at busybox (ie. boot failure aid). Root delay is not your issue; but the failure to let the upgrade complete being your problem.

Selecting an old kernel is also taking it into busybox
